# Best way to offset an enumerable with itself

Tags: c#, linq

Given a source `IEnumerable<T>` and a positive integer offset and a merge function `Func<T,T,TResult>` I would like to produce a new `IEnumerable<TResult>`

A possible signature follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Offset<T, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int offset, Func<T,T,TResult> selector
);
```

Here's an example using the following inputs which will produce the offset enumerable and select the sum of the offset parts.

```
typeof(T) = typeof(int);
typeof(TResult) = typeof(int);
source = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
offset = 1;
selector = (original, offsetValue) => original + offsetValue;

result = source.Offset(offset, selector);

expected = new int[]{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17};
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEquals(result));
```

A very important goal here is to enumerate the source `IEnumerable<T>` only once.

Comment: Where does that first value come from? I'd expect `source.Count() - offset` elements.

Comment: I was imagining you could find the first result value by moving the numerator forward 'offset' times, while having saved the first enumerated value from source... thinking about it, sounds like I need to be saving the offset number of elements in a local array or someting

Comment: you mean tweeking the Enumerator?

Comment: just manually enumerating it... so maybe it would work like this, enumerate the enumerator offset number of times and save results to local queue, then continue enumerating and yield return selector.Invoke(queue.Deqeue(), enumerator.Current)

Comment: @JonSkeet I misunderstood your first value comment, I suppose the first value of 0 in unncessary, and should not be included. I've updated the question.

Comment: @mhand Since you appear to have a solution in mind, why haven't you tried implementing it?  If/when you have any problems with that approach, then you can ask about it here.

Comment: Yes, the solution came to mind during this short conversation. I'm implementing it now. I'll post it for any who stumble here.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `Skip()` then passing `selector` to `Select()`?

Comment: Calling skip will inevitably end in multiple enumerations of the IEnumerable which goes against my main goal

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the previous `offset` items.  A `Queue` is likely the most effective tool for doing this.  If there are sufficient items in said queue, pair the current item with the dequeued item and yield it.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Offset<T, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int offset, Func<T, T, TResult> selector)
{
    var queue = new Queue<T>(offset);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (queue.Count >= offset)
            yield return selector(queue.Dequeue(), item);

        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is almost exactly what I ended up with, thanks for the super fast response

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sounds like you need to buffer the results, e.g. in an array:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Offset<T, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int offset, Func<T,T,TResult> selector)
{
    // TODO: Shenanigans to validate arguments eagerly

    T[] buffer = new T[offset];
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < offset && iterator.MoveNext(); i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = iterator.Current;
        }

        int index = 0;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            T old = buffer[index];
            T current = iterator.Current;
            yield return selector(old, current);
            buffer[index] = current;
            index = (index + 1) % offset;
        }
    }
}
```

That at least works with your example...

Comment: [Using a queue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659590/1159478) is quite a bit easier than explicitly managing the circular buffer yourself, since the queue itself is of course implemented using a circular buffer.

Comment: @Servy: Well, it's shorter... I find them about the same for readability. I quite like the way it's obvious in my code that there are two distinct phases: building up the buffer, and then yielding a pair-up. Given that the circular buffer is always a fixed size, and we never really "drain" it, the array is pretty simple.

Comment: thanks for the super fast responses, I like using the queue due to simplicity.